# Is it possible to win $2048$ in a $3 \times 3$ grid?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I was playing the famous $2048$ game with the non-standard $3 \times 3$ grid. I quickly realized it was awfully difficult to even get up to $256$, with the best possible algorithm(of course in my head, not using a computer).

So my question is - **Is it possible to win $2048$ in $3 \times 3$ grid? If yes, can it be shown mathematically?**

Comment: To get a $2048$ tile, in the turns leading up to it you would need one of each of $1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4$ and then either two $2$'s or an additional $4$.  How many tiles does that require?  How many spaces do you have available to work with?

Comment: @JMoravitz: Thats exactly what my thinking was. I need $2^n$ tiles for each $n$, leading to $1024$, which itself requires $9$ grids, and then $2$'s or $4$'s to continue generating.

Comment: @sbp You should show the rules of the game.

Answer (score 5):

Let's prove by induction that with $n$ squares whose initial values are all below $2^n$ you can get at most $1$ square with $2^n$ and all other squares will have less.

Base: $n=1$. You can get a $2$ and that's it, which equals $2^1$

Step: Suppose we have $n+1$ squares, and let the inductive hypothesis be that with $n$ squares you can at most get $1$ square with $2^n$ and all other squares have less than that

Well, before we can get to $2^{n+1}$ on the $n+1$ squares board you need to get two squares with $2^n$. Now, once you get one square with $2^n$, you need to use the remaining $n$ squares to get another $2^n$, because the square with the $2^n$ will be useless for that endeavor. And since you just got your first $2^n$ square, that means that all those squares have values below $2^n$, and thus we can apply the inductive hypothesis.

So, by inductive hypothesis, you might be able to get one square with $2^n$ with those remaining $n$ squares, but all other squares will have less than that. So, even if you can get another $2^n$ square, once you combine the two squares with $2^n$ to get a square with $2^{n+1}$, you are left with $n$ squares all with less than $2^n$, and by inductive hypothesis the most you can get from those squares is just $1$ more square with $2^n$, and the rest will have less (again, the square with $2^n$ will not help in getting any bigger number, since it cannot be combined with any of the other $n$ squares while they all have values of less than that, which is why we can apply the inductive hypothesis).

So, you cannot get a second square with $2^{n+1}$ and so you cannot get a square with $2^{n+2}$ either. Hence, you can at best get $1$ square with $2^{n+1}$ and all other squares will have less.

Applying this general result to your case: on a $3 \times 3$ grid, we can at most get $2^9=512$

**Edit**

Apparently the game spawns 4 pieces once and a while.  So, for the best case scenario we can assume that it always spawns 4 pieces, and that means that in the proof above we can simply multiply everything by 2, meaning that the highest score possible is $1024$

Comment: I get to 512 and a bit higher all the time.  Remember, about 10% of the generations will be 4s, so there are some invalid assumptions here I think.

Comment: Sorry but the answer here is false. You can go to 1024. The writer forgets that 4 can spawn and not just 2's. I'll add an image in the solution.

Comment: @mashtock  I didn't realize you could get 4's ... I updated my Answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm an experimentalist so you won't find a mathematical prove here, only screenshots from the game. In order to get to 1024 you need to surpass the following scenario: [image]

In order to achieve it you need to be very lucky that the next slide would spawn a 4. The next tough situation is the following:
[image]

This is one of the highest scores possible in the game for a 3 by 3 board. Again to continue you need to be lucky again to spawn a 4, but that would only get your first 512. In order to get the second 1024 you need to spawn an 8, which is not possible. The highest tile possible is 1024.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible!! The turns right before the creation of the 2048 block would fill the 3x3 with $$1024,\ 512,\ 256$$

$$32\ \ ,\ \ 64\ ,\ 128$$ $$16\ ,\ \ 8\ \ ,\ \ 4$$

This is possible because in the standard game, about 10% of the generations will be 4s. In general, we can show that the max possible value of a tile can be described as $2^{n+2}$ where $n$ is the number of squares in the puzzle.

Comment: This setup is game over, there's nothing to combine with the "4" tile.

Answer (score 0):

the largest tile you can get is a 1024, you need a lucky 4 spawn, (about 10%)
and if you were using the "snake" method the board would look like
4  ,4  ,8
16 ,32 ,64
128,256,512

however, this is nearly impossible to do, a more consistent method is what we call
"DPDF" or Double Perimeter Defense Formation which is when you arrange the board like this, and feed in the from corners.

8  ,2  ,x
64 ,16 ,4
256,128,4

the 8 2 and 4s are where you combine.
(i have gotten 3 1024s, but reached that last 4 around 35 times.)
best of luck!